# How to check for a function's existence in a cocos2d-x class?

Tags: c++, templates, cocos2d-x, sfinae

I have lots of nodes from CCNode subclasses and some of them have the function `ccTouchBegan(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent)`.
Now my question is if it's possible to check if they own this particular function with SFINAE.
I tried to make it work with the help of that thread: [Is it possible to write a template to check for a function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence) but I can't.

Here's what I have:

```
template <typename T>
class hasMethodCCTouchBegan
{
    typedef char yes;
    typedef long no;

    template <typename C> static yes test( decltype(&C::ccTouchBegan) ) ;
    template <typename C> static no test(...);

public:
    enum { value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes) };
};
```

Honestly I have no clue what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally use (in C++11):

```
#include <cstdint>

#define DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(traitsName, funcName, signature)               \
    template <typename U>                                                   \
    class traitsName                                                        \
    {                                                                       \
    private:                                                                \
        template<typename T, T> struct helper;                              \
        template<typename T>                                                \
        static std::uint8_t check(helper<signature, &funcName>*);           \
        template<typename T> static std::uint16_t check(...);               \
    public:                                                                 \
        static                                                              \
        constexpr bool value = sizeof(check<U>(0)) == sizeof(std::uint8_t); \
    }

// Create your traits:
DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE(has_ccTouchBegan, T::ccTouchBegan, bool (T::*)(CCTouch *, CCEvent *));
```

Comment: I get a bunch of errors at line DEFINE_HAS_SIGNATURE, first thing is `Unknown type name 'constexpr'`

Comment: VS doesn't support `constexpr`, so you may replace it by `const` here.

Comment: Okay, I'm using the default compiler in XCode for C++ Language Dialect & Library. Maybe that's it, but I get other errors in other classes when I change it to C++11.

EDIT: Cool that solved that issue. Now I have the error `Expected unqualified-id` at `void (T::)`. Is it correct to implement all this in the header and nothing else?

Comment: Sorry, `*` was missing: last parameter should be `void (T::*)(CCTouch *, CCEvent *)` (assuming the method returns `void`).

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! Now do I only have to use `has_ccTouchBegan` in my main method? For example: `has_ccTouchBegan<currentNode>();` Or is there more to it?

Comment: Now, you may use `has_ccTouchBegan<currentNode>::value` in your code, for `static_assert`, tag dispatching or SFINAE for example.

Comment: I hope that's my last question, because I can't seem to make that work. I use `std::cout << has_ccTouchBegan<CCLayer>::value;` in my main and it returns 0 even though I know that CCLayer contains that function.

Comment: I got it working, I thought that this function was a void because `ccTouchMoved`, `ccTouchEnded` and `ccTouchCancelled` are voids, only `ccTouchBegan` is a `bool`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class C>
decltype(&C::ccTouchBegan, std::true_type())
methodHelper(int);

template<class C>
std::false_type
methodHelper(...);

template<class C>
struct hasMethodCCTouchBegan : decltype(methodHelper<C>(0))
{
};
```

This won't work if `ccTouchBegan` is overloaded. If you want to test whether `ccTouchBegan` can be called with certain arguments then you can change `&C::ccTouchBegan` to `std::declval<C>().ccTouchBegan(std::declval<CCTouch*>(), std::declval<CCEvent*>())`.

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer. But now I get errors for example: `Unknown type name 'decltype'`
Do i still need template <typename T>
`class hasMethodCCTouchBegan
{
    typedef char one;
    typedef long two;` before that code you wrote?

Comment: `decltype` is a C++11 keyword. I assumed you were using C++11 by your use of it.